# Can I apply the same formula to multiple fields in one go?

Tags: pentaho, kettle

In the Pentaho Data Integration (ETL) tool (Kettle), is there an easy way to apply the same formula to multiple fields at once?

Let's say I have these fields: date1, date2, date3, ... , date20 and, for each of these dates, I want to extract the year. Do I have to manually define 20 new fields and 20 new formulae, or can I do it in one go?

Alteryx has the 'multi field formula' tool, which does exactly this, and I want to understand if Pentaho has something similar.

Alternatively, is there a way to script something like this? I understand Kettle has an experimental Javascript step, but the development of the step has been abandoned. I also understand there are R and Ruby plugins, but I am not familiar with those (I tend to use Python).

Comment: As per my knowledge, PDI doesnt support mutli field formula unlike Alteryx. As you rightly said, you need to define the formula for each field you select. I understand it is really frustrating at times. But one thing you can do is to raise a jira tkt this as an enhancement in Pentaho community.

Comment: If u interested u can try to use User Defined Java Class Step to iterate over stream row, to find out all element with Date data type, then  change their format, put back in row and pass row to next step. But It sounds complicated and error prone, and don't worth unless u have really huge amount of such fields

Comment: @simar i did tried it once. its really frustrating and highly error prone. Agreed. There is no point even trying this feature :)